# Finding the variance across columns for a single row in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My database is set up like this

```
CustomerNumber  Bill_Apr   Bill_Mar    Bill_Feb    Bill_Jan
```

I need to create a new column that has the variance across the monthly bills.

If I can't do this, will I need to restructure the database to have multiple customer numbers with each month's bill as a different row?  I would much rather set up to where I can calculate across columns.

Comment: You can use a view, or just use select statements to get the numbers you're looking for. You can't add a column in the base table that will do what you want, though - unless you manually add the total once all the other numbers are populated (you shouldn't want to have a column like that).

Comment: When I run this code

SELECT VARIANCE(BILL_APR,BILL_MAR,BILL_FEB) AS VARIANCE_MONTH FROM table

I am told that variance can only be used for one column  I want to have it go across all the bill columns and generate a variable that will hold the value

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you restructure the table to be 1 row per customer per month. With your current structure, what happens next year with January? Do you overwrite the value? What happens next month where you don't have a column? Do you add a column and then update your calculated column?

I would recommend the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Bills
(CustomerNumber int,
MonthYear varchar(30),
Bill double,
)
```

Then, you could write a view or query that would look like

```
SELECT CustomerNumber, VARIANCE(Bill) as BillVariance
FROM Bills
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
```

This will return the statistical variance for all of the bills by each customer.